I got some POC where I need to seggregate delay data based on shift
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_timestamp, date_format, col, expr
spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "2024-10-19T13:01:17.000+00:00", "2024-10-21T13:01:17.000+00:00"),
        (2, "2024-10-10T11:01:17.000+00:00", "2024-10-10T12:01:17.000+00:00"),
        (3, "2024-10-11T06:00:00.000+00:00", "2024-10-12T05:59:59.000+00:00"),
        (4, "2024-10-21T14:00:00.000+00:00", "2024-10-21T15:16:07.000+00:00"),
        (5, "2024-10-24T04:00:00.000+00:00", "2024-10-24T11:00:00.000+00:00"),
    ],
    ["delay_id", "delay_start", "delay_end"],
).withColumn("delay_start_adjusted", expr("to_timestamp(delay_start)")).withColumn(
    "delay_end_adjusted", expr("to_timestamp(delay_end)")
).withColumn(
    "delay_start_adjusted_yyyymmdd",
    date_format(col("delay_start_adjusted"), "yyyyMMdd"),
).withColumn(
    "delay_end_adjusted_yyyymmdd", date_format(col("delay_end_adjusted"), "yyyyMMdd")
).withColumn(
    "delay_start_adjusted_hhmmss", date_format(col("delay_start_adjusted"), "HH:mm:ss")
).withColumn(
    "delay_end_adjusted_hhmmss", date_format(col("delay_end_adjusted"), "HH:mm:ss")
).createOrReplaceTempView(
    "temp_Delay"
)

spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("20241010",),
        ("20241011",),
        ("20241012",),
        ("20241019",),
        ("20241020",),
        ("20241021",),
        ("20241022",),
        ("20241023",),
        ("20241024",),
    ],
    ["date_key"],
).createOrReplaceTempView("temp_DateView")

Usually there will be some delays in the systems due to X reasons, each reason has delay ID and those delays u need to segregate on below shift timings. need to use date table for joining purpose.
Usually the shift timings are 0-8, 8-16, 16-24.
Output I need is shift (add -6hrs to output shift)
for exmaple delay id 3
actual  delay (3,'2024-10-11T06:00:00.000+00:00', '2024-10-12T05:59:59.000+00:00')
shift wise table
date_key    delay_id    delay_start_adjusted_for_the_shift  delay_end_adjusted_for_the_shift    shift_code
20241011    3   2024-10-11T00:00:00.000+00:00   2024-10-11T07:59:59.000+00:00   S1
20241011    3   2024-10-11T08:00:00.000+00:00   2024-10-11T15:59:59.000+00:00   S2
20241011    3   2024-10-11T16:00:00.000+00:00   2024-10-11T23:59:59.000+00:00   S3

I kindly request that you format the code

Did you look at spark structures streaming? Your problem seems to be a basic streaming use case that uses watermarks
